# Export products with selected customer group specific price?

Tags: price, export, customer-group

Is there a way to export product data to CSV with customer group specific price?

This would be needed for integration to the retailer's system. There are special prices for this retailer and we would like to automate the price and stock updates to their system.

Comment: What kind of "product data" are you looking for? I don't believe this is possible out-of-box, but group pricing data is stored in `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.

Comment: SKU, group specific price and qty would be a great start.